# PowerShell cmdlet not working with string concatenation

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a PowerShell cmdlet with a variable but seem to be having some issues. If I try to concatenate a string (no matter how) and pass that to the cmdlet as the value of a parameter the command fails. However, if I pass the actual string it works fine. Complete example in image.

[image: Demo Here]

Comment: Does something like this work `$first = ":\Temp"
$second = "C$first"
Get-ChildItem -Path $second` and what is the result of `$searchQuery -eq the actual string`?

Comment: Also please don't just post code as an image. Read why [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I can only assume that searchQuery is not a string. Somehow?.  You force it to be a string by adding [string]$searchQuery.=.

Comment: Ditto to what Doug said. If you are not promoting these two, then why are you concatenating it at all. Just past the whole query string natively as in your working version or did you try this... [Submit-PnpSearchQuery -Query "$SearchQuery $WebpartId"]